# Returning to the last form the user was on

Tags: c#

I have multiple forms and i can make them all go to a certain form through the click of one button, but how do I give one button the ability to go back to the last page the user was on, and not just the form before the current one? This is for my 'help' form, as users can visit the form through many other forms. My coding was as follows. **I am using Winforms**

```
namespace Spanish_Quiz
{

    public partial class Help : Form
    {
        public Help()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CenterToScreen();
        }

        private void btnBackToStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Homescreen Homescreen = new Homescreen();
            Homescreen.Show();
            Homescreen.Activate();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            /*This is where my problem  is,
            what code do I write here that could be similar to 
            my 'back to start' button's code?*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Stack of Forms. You can push items onto the stack and pop items when navigating back

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the ui technology you are using (i.e., `winforms` or `wpf`). While you're there you could [clean up the formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)